# how we show two picker with startTime and EndTime using react-native-community/dateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to pick two time startTime and EndTime but the values we saved in useState changes start-Time in the place of EndTime and sometime the picker select auto value for startTime when i pick endTime and vice-versa.how can i manage the states and picker to only save one value at a time without changing value of second States

````
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [fromTime, setFromTime] = useState(new Date());
  const [toTime, setToTime] = useState(new Date());
const onFromTimeChange = (event, selectedFromTime) => {
    const currentFrom = selectedFromTime || fromTime;
    setShow(!show);
    setFromTime(currentFrom);
  };
  const onToTimeChange = (event, selectedToTime) => {
    const currentToTime = selectedToTime || toTime;
    setShow(!show);
    setToTime(currentToTime);
  };
  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };
  const showFromTimepicker = () => {
    showMode("time");
  };
  const showToTimepicker = () => {
    showMode("time");
  };
return ( <Text style={styles.workUkText}>
              Job Availability (Select Hours)
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.ukWorkView}>
              <Text style={styles.fromAvailability}>From</Text>
              <View style={styles.fromTime}>
                <TextInput
                  onTouchStart={showFromTimepicker}
                  style={{ fontWeight: "600", fontSize: 16 }}
                  value={moment(fromTime).format("HH : mm")}
                  onChangeText={onFromTimeChange}
                />
                {show && (
                  <DateTimePicker
                    testID="dateTimePicker"
                    value={fromTime}
                    mode={mode}
                    is24Hour={true}
                    display="default"
                    onChange={onFromTimeChange}
                  />
                )}
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.fromAvailability}>To</Text>
              <View style={styles.fromTime}>
                <TextInput
                  onTouchStart={showToTimepicker}
                  style={{ fontWeight: "600", fontSize: 16 }}
                  value={moment(toTime).format("HH : mm")}
                  onChangeText={onToTimeChange}
                />
                {show && (
                  <DateTimePicker
                    testID="TimePicker"
                    value={toTime}
                    mode={mode}
                    is24Hour={true}
                    display="default"
                    onChange={onToTimeChange}
                  />
                )}
              </View>
)
.```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are using same state `show` for both the picker. using an other `show` state will help solve your issue
or to do with a single state you can do something like this

```js
 const [show, setShow] = useState('none');
 const [fromTime, setFromTime] = useState(new Date());
 const [toTime, setToTime] = useState(new Date());

 const onFromTimeChange = (event, selectedFromTime) => {
    const currentFrom = selectedFromTime || fromTime;
    setShow('none');
    setFromTime(currentFrom);
  };
  const onToTimeChange = (event, selectedToTime) => {
    const currentToTime = selectedToTime || toTime;
    setShow('none');
    setToTime(currentToTime);
  };
  const showMode = (currentMode,pickerType) => {
    setShow(pickerType);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };


return ( <Text style={styles.workUkText}>
              Job Availability (Select Hours)
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.ukWorkView}>
              <Text style={styles.fromAvailability}>From</Text>
              <View style={styles.fromTime}>
                <TextInput
                  onTouchStart={()=>showMode("time","showFromPicker")}
                  style={{ fontWeight: "600", fontSize: 16 }}
                  value={moment(fromTime).format("HH : mm")}
                  onChangeText={onFromTimeChange}
                />
                {show==="showFromPicker" && (
                  <DateTimePicker
                    testID="dateTimePicker"
                    value={fromTime}
                    mode={mode}
                    is24Hour={true}
                    display="default"
                    onChange={onFromTimeChange}
                  />
                )}
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.fromAvailability}>To</Text>
              <View style={styles.fromTime}>
                <TextInput
                  onTouchStart={()=>showMode("time","showToPicker")}
                  style={{ fontWeight: "600", fontSize: 16 }}
                  value={moment(toTime).format("HH : mm")}
                  onChangeText={onToTimeChange}
                />
                {show==="showToPicker" && (
                  <DateTimePicker
                    testID="TimePicker"
                    value={toTime}
                    mode={mode}
                    is24Hour={true}
                    display="default"
                    onChange={onToTimeChange}
                  />
                )}
              </View>
)
```

Comment: Yes it is working. it was the problem with showPicker auto open two time and select time auto.